# Regression Output Acuracy

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

Suppose I have a logistic regression formula that takes x as input and y is the estimated output. The regression is based on a historical set of x and y values.

How can I give an accuracy percentage on a y-estimated for a future x value? In other words, the probability that the y-estimated will be correct for a future x value?

Comment: You are looking for a prediction interval.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. That is what I was thinking, but I was wondering is there way to get a single value (prediction % or confidence %)  and not an interval with a min & max? I am guessing probably no

Comment: A prediction interval will give you a mean prediction with a 95 % or any other percentage prediction interval, this is not about min and max.

Comment: What I mean is its an interval (a range) that the estimated will fall in based on the percentage, but I wondering if its possible to have a prediction value essentially, the probability the estimated will be exactly as actual based on %

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: For example, I can say I am 95% confident that the y-estimated will be between x and z. But can I say I am ?% confident that the y estimated will be exactly y estimated?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you edit your question with a specific example.